# How to hide the knob of jSlider?

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I need to customize the knob of JSlider. I need to put my own knob's image over default knob of Jslider. 
The problem is that currently two knobs are coming in response. One my own knob and second the default knob. Please tell me how i can i hide the default knob or any other solution.

Below code is used to do so.

```
public class ImageTest {

 JSlider slider;
 JLabel label;

 public ImageTest()
 {

  JPanel panel = new BackgroundPanel();

  slider = new BackgroundSlider();

  slider.setMaximum(300);
  slider.setMinimum(0);
  slider.setValue(50);

  slider.setExtent(10);
  slider.addChangeListener(new MyChangeAction());
  label = new JLabel("50");
  panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

  panel.setSize(797,402);
  slider.setOpaque(false);
  slider.setPaintTrack(false);

  label.setOpaque(false);

  slider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(340, 20));

  GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraintsSlider = new GridBagConstraints();
  gridBagConstraintsSlider.gridy = 0;
  gridBagConstraintsSlider.gridx = 0;
  gridBagConstraintsSlider.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  gridBagConstraintsSlider.insets = new Insets(0, 283, 260, 0);


  GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
  gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
  gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
  gridBagConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 50, 240, 0);

  panel.add(slider, gridBagConstraintsSlider);
  panel.add(label, gridBagConstraints);

  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
  frame.setSize(797,402);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  WindowUtil.locateCenter(frame);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ImageTest im= new ImageTest();
 }

 public class MyChangeAction implements ChangeListener{
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce){
   int value = slider.getValue();
   String str = Integer.toString(value);
   label.setText(str);
   if(value==300)
   {
    label.setText("Max");
   }

  }
 }

}



class BackgroundSlider extends JSlider
{
 Image image;
 public BackgroundSlider()
 {
  try
  {
   image = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(new File("slider.png"));
  }
  catch (Exception e) { /*handled in paintComponent()*/ }
 }

 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
  super.paintComponent(g); 
  if (image != null)
   g.drawImage(image, this.getValue(),(int)this.getAlignmentY(),10,20,this);


  g.setColor(Color.RED); 
  //draw a centered horizontal line 
  g.drawRect(15,this.getHeight()-1,this.getValue(),this.getHeight()+2); 
  g.fillRect(15,this.getHeight()-1,this.getValue(),this.getHeight()+2); 

 }
}
```

Thanks
Jyoti

Comment: Jyoti Have a look at http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=422377

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide the knob, override the UIManager's `Slider.horizontalThumbIcon` property with an blank icon, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Slider.horizontalThumbIcon",new Icon(){
        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            //do nothing
        }
    });

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 30, 15);
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);

    f.add(slider);
    f.setSize(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with a different BasicSliderUI looks like this:

```
public class SuperSlider extends JSlider {
    public SuperSlider(int min, int max, int value) {
        super(min,max,value);
        setUI(new SuperSliderUI(this));
    }
    private class SuperSliderUI extends BasicSliderUI {
        @Override
        public void paintThumb(Graphics g) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The UIManager solution only works in the Metal LAF from what I can tell.

If you want to change the behavour of the UI then you need to change the UI. In this case you would need to the BasicSliderUI (or one of its sub classes). Then I believe you would need to override the paintThumb() method.

Comment: +1 This has been my experience, too. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898259