# Is there a way to flip a JSlider so that the slider arrow points upwards?

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I've been trying to find a way to do this for a while now and can't quite seem to figure it out. I know you can change the orientation of a JSlider, using setOrientation(HORIZONTAL|VERTICAL), and that you can also invert the scale, using setInverted(true). My problem is as follows:

1) The JSlider needs to be horizontal;
2) The JSlider needs to be below the data;
3) The arrow (pointy-tip) on the actual slider should be pointing upwards, not downwards (i.e.: towards the data).

The only way I can fathom to do this is to overwrite the paintComponent method from JComponent and entirely re-code it for a custom JSlider, which seems a tad ridiculous, and I'm not even sure it would work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it's very LaF dependent, because the JSlider has an arrow only in Metal and, depending on current theme, GTK LaF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the thumbnail used in UIManager [How to hide the knob of jSlider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021191/how-to-hide-the-knob-of-jslider)

```
UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put(
    "Slider.horizontalThumbIcon",
    new Icon('your_icon')
);
```

However, this would be done to all sliders in your program.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed! I'm not surprised that Java won't let you do it simply for one layout element, that would be way too easy.