# JSlider arrow pointing left?

Tags: java, swing, custom-component, jslider

I have a question about getting a JSlider to point the left instead of right.. BUT, I need it to do so only for one JSlider. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027289/is-there-a-way-to-flip-a-jslider-so-that-the-slider-arrow-points-upwards) is very similar but the answer to it only helped if you wanted all JSliders to point the wrong way. Here is a photoshopped image of what i want.

[image: JSliders]

Comment: What L&F are you using??

Comment: Whatever is standard L&F on a mac.

Comment: Well regarding in the image you post it looks like `Nimbus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it. All i needed to do was make a new class.

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JSlider;

public class ReversedJSlider extends JSlider{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ReversedJSlider() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
        tx.translate(50, 0);
        tx.scale(-1, 1);
        tx.translate(-50, 0);
        g2d.setTransform(tx);
        super.paintComponent(g2d);
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure I'd agree with this, it will work in your case, but the problem is if you now apply labels to the slider, they will be mirrored...just saying ;)